# Flipboard android layout choice

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-fragments, flipboard

I was wondering if anybody had any idea about how to mimic this Flipboard ui in android. I'm thinking that they might be using fragments, using gridview and list view, but the implementation of the gridview makes me wonder. Gridview with rows with three columns and a row with one column confuses me. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

View the Flipboard UI: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNvxt.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this library is what you are looking for https://github.com/openaphid/android-flip

Comment: Nope, I'm not looking for a way to accomplish the flipview, but a way of creating this complex layout (gridview and listview)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is StaggeredGridView.
Maybe this [link](https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView) helps you.

Comment: I'm not sure if the StaggeredGridView would work judging from the documentation I read about it. I'll try and come back to you, thanks. If you can implement it and have time to do it, I'll be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

This approach can help to implement such layouts.

1. Create a gridview or create grid columns
2. Add this view as Header view for Listview